# Configuring WSL to use Linux file system yields "...Bad escape sequence..."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL2, attempts to configure an Ubuntu 20 distro to use the linux file system results in

```
Settings could not be reloaded from file. Check for syntax errors, including trailing commas.
* Line 71, Column 38
  Bad escape sequence in string
See Line 71, Column 47 for detail.
```

distro is Ubuntu

settings.json includes

```
"hidden": false,
"name": "WSL-Ubuntu",
"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
"startingDirectory": "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\"  < line 71
```

col 38 is between `:` and `"`

Comment: You need to use \\ instead of \

Comment: However, \\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\  for example, yields `The system cannot find the path specified. [process exited with code 4294967295] ` when trying to open a the `WSL-Ubuntu` tab.. Several variations were tried, e.g., without home, with home and a user name, etc.

Comment: If you navigate to \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\ within File Explorer what is displayed? I would also use the GUI instead of manually editing the JSON file. Microsoft’s documentation indicates “\\\\wsl$\\DISTRO NAME\\home\\” is correct

Comment: Hah! For one, I hadn't scrolled down in the GUI to see the entry for WSL-Ubuntu. All that needed was an addition \ at the front end. I will gladly accept an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In WSL2, attempts to configure an Ubuntu 20 distro to use the linux file system results in a syntax error

You can use the GUI within Windows Terminal to configure the home directory or modify it to the following:

```
\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\
```